# How can I scroll a web page smoothly using JavaScript, without the scrolling being interrupted by the next scroll command?

Tags: javascript, scroll, mouse, smooth-scrolling

This question is for when using the mouse wheel on an external mouse, not the touchpad.

I'm working on a program that modifies the mouse's behavior.
I'm using window.scrollBy, but window.scroll or window.scrollTo or something else could also work.

I've included the code below for a test page that you could copy and paste.
It works fine for one scroll, but not for multiple scrolls at once.

One scroll of the mouse wheel scrolls smoothly up or down.
But when multiple scrolls are sent quickly, the page actually scrolls slower in a jerky motion.
The problem seems to be that before the initial scroll is finished, the next scroll interrupts it.

For example in the code I typed out below:
If you scroll slowly down 5 times, then quickly up 10 times, the page doesn't scroll back up to the top.

It makes me wonder how it works normally in Windows or Chrome OS or other operating systems.
I've tried to research this already but couldn't find a good explanation of how it normally works.
Normally multiple scrolls at once increase the scrolling smoothly, while the code below does not.

How does this normally work?
What code can be used to make the page scroll properly?

```
<html><head>
<title>Scroll Test</title>

<script>

window.addEventListener("mousewheel", processEvent, {passive: false});

function processEvent()
{

event.preventDefault();

var scrollAmount = event.deltaY < 0 ? -100 : 100;

window.scrollBy({left:0, top:scrollAmount, behavior:"smooth"});

}

</script>

</head><body align="center">
<b>Test Area:</b>
<p>
</body></html>

<script>
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {document.body.innerHTML += i + "<br>";}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either throttle the mousewheel/wheel event using something like lodash:

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", _.debounce(processEvent, 500), {passive: false});
```

Another thing to note, the window *scrollBy* function may not be as smooth a scroll as the GSAP ScrollTo plugin:

```
gsap.to(window, {duration: 2, scrollTo: 400});
```

Some potential solutions depending on if you're cool with external libraries!  :)

Comment: Those are some interesting ideas, but I would prefer to use plain JavaScript, if you have any other solutions.